# The moore penrose inverse ($A^+$) minimizes $\left\lVert AX-I_m\right\rVert_F$

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Question: show that $A^+$ minimizes $\left\lVert AX-I_m\right\rVert_F$.

Which means that we should prove that $\left\lVert AA^+ -I_m\right\rVert _F = min \left\lVert AX-I_m\right\rVert_F$.

$A$ is $m×n$ matrix and $I$ is the identity matrix.

My attempt: We can simplify the problem to $AX-I_m = [AX_1 - e_1 ,...., AX_m - e_m]$. $e_i$ is the element of our basis.

Based on the Euclidean norm, we can prove that the original problem is made of $m$ ordinary least square problems.
Now we get that each problem has the solution $x^* = A^+ e_i$.
If the solution to each of these $m$ problem is represented by $x_i^*$, I want to prove that $X^*=[{x_1^*,..,x_m^*}]$ (the solution to the original problem) is equal to $A^+$ the moore penrose inverse. So the question is now: prove $X^*=A^+$.

Ps: I only know SVD, QR decomposition and the norm of a matrix.

Comment: What exactly *is* the problem?

Comment: @Paul Sinclair Prove $A^+$ minimizes $AX=I_m$. This is a least square problem in numerical linear algebra. $A^+$ is the moore penrose inverse.

Comment: Minimizing $AX=I_m$ makes no sense. What does it mean to minimize an equation?

Comment: You seem you want to minimize the distance in 2-norm, right? State that! Also what is $A^+$, I assume pseudoinverse? State that!

Comment: @Gerry Myerson can you check my post again? I've edited it.

Comment: @Shashi please check my edit.

Comment: Don't you have $X^*=[x_1^*,...,x_m^*]=[A^+e_1,...,A^+e_m]=A^+$ by the construction you did?

Comment: @Shashi Yes, is my approach correct?

Comment: What properties of $A^{+}$ are you allowed to assume?

Comment: Notice $A^+ e_i$ is just the $i$th column of $A^+$. So $x_i=A^+e_i$ means the $i$th column of $X$ matches the $i$th column of $A^+$, or $X=A^+$. So you're already done!